# Is there a way in Xcode to browse the contents of the iOS app's NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: xcode

For debugging I have saved out a number of files in the [standard system directory 'Document'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url), i.e. the NSDocumentDirectory, the one returned by this call

```swift
let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

If I set a breakpoint in my app is there a way in Xcode on the Mac of browsing and examining those files from the iPhone my app is being debugged on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the `Container` of app in your mac and see the files that are there

In Xcode , select the device, select the app name under Installed Apps, click the settings gearbox, then select **Download** container.  In finder, `double finger tap the package` and `select Show package contents`.

**see example:**
 **[image: go to Window -> Devices]**

Comment: How did you "select the device"?

Comment: Got it: Window > Devices and Simulators

Answer (score 0):

iOS debug NSDocumentDirectory

```
Window -> Devices and Simulators -> <select_device> -> <select_app> -> ...(three dots icon) -> Download Container... -> <navigate_to_downloaded_bundle>.xcappdata -> <right_click> -> Show Package Contents -> AppData/Documents
```

[image]
[image]